# How to capture values with a space after hyphen with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some javascript code wherein I am trying to capture values from a string that match either of the following cases:

**"-H" or "- H" (note the space in the second case)**

I was able to capture the first case with [the following regex](https://regex101.com/r/p0BxkS/1):

```
(?=\S*['-])([a-zA-Z'-]+)
```

However I can't seem to be able to figure out how to capture the case with the space in it.

This is an example of what I am trying to extract from.
I am ONLY trying to capture the **-H** value. from this sentence:

```
This is non-refundable -H
```

Comment: Maybe use `/\B-\s*[A-Z]\b/g`? See https://regex101.com/r/mSUJXX/1

Comment: Wow you are so fast! This is great, thank you so much. Could you tell me how I can change it to also capture words? ie "-TEST" and  "- TEST"
Please feel free to reply as an answer and I will award it as it perfectly answers my original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/\B-\s*[A-Z]+\b/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mSUJXX/2)

*Details*:

- `\B` - a non-word boundary (immediately on the left, there must be start of string or a non-word char)
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `[A-Z]+` - one or more ASCII uppercase letters
- `\b` -  a word boundary (immediately on the right, there must be end of string or a non-word char)

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "-H - H\n-TEST - TEST";
const regex = /\B-\s*[A-Z]+\b/g;
console.log(text.match(regex));
```